# Store PHP variable through HTML button

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I am trying to store a PHP session variable through a HTML button. For example I run a `FOR loop` contains a HTML button and it shows up 5 buttons: `A ,B ,C, D, E`. I want to click on the button `C` and it will redirect to a new page that shows up (echo) $C

How could I achieve that?

I have tried the following code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($hashtag);$i++){ 

 echo '<button type="submit" name="insert" value="';    

 $_SESSION["hashtag_search"]=$hashtag[$i]; 

 echo '"><span class="label label-danger" ><a target="_blank" href="http://link.net/search-hashtag.php">'.$hashtag[$i].' ('.$hashtag_count[$i].')</a></span></button>';

}
```

on the search-hashtag.php i got

```
echo $_SESSION["hashtag_search"];
```

but the SESSION variable would store the last `$hashtag[$i]` (when $i maxed) not the `$hashtag[$i]` of the clicked button

Comment: You cannot ask for the code directly here.You'll haveto show us what is the code that you've tried and then ask it here for more info on [how to ask question see help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @IshanMahajan ok tks imma update my code here

Comment: it always store the last bcz session variable doesn't change at all u r always doing `$_SESSION["hashtag_search"]=$hashtag[$i];`  so at last in for loop session always store the last `$hashtag[$i]`

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the session in each loop so it won't work. You should use a GET Method to send the variable.

index.php

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://link.net/search-hashtag.php?hashtag='.$hashtag[$i].'">
```

search-hashtag.php

```
$a = $_GET["hashtag"];
echo($a);
```

Comment: i tried your method but got a blank page ( i got a issue with my error_log not appearing )

Comment: oh got it it's the problem with the hashtag itself ( the hashtag block the url ). Thank you !

Comment: you should also change your for loop to `foreach($hashtag as $value)`. Documentation here [link](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)